# ARM Compiled QEMU - "standard VGA not available"

Tags: arch-linux, graphics, qemu

I followed [this](http://xecdesign.com/compiling-qemu/) guide to compile QEMU so that I could run a Raspberry Pi Archlinux image in it - which I learned how to do in this [guide](http://ebalaskas.gr/blog/2013/03/25/raspberry-pi-with-archlinux-under-qemu/).

I'm trying to run x-server on the virtualized Archlinux image, but to do so, I must have a graphics device.  I installed some generic drivers (i.e. Vesa) for now, but my QEMU isn't showing any graphics devices to be available.

As a startup parameter, I tried `-vga cirrus` which gave me the error:

> Error: Cirrus VGA not available

I then tried to have QEMU emulate a different graphics device using the `-vga std` parameter, but then got this error:

> Error: standard VGA not available

Where do I go from here?  I have a gut feeling that this issue is due to the fact that I compiled QEMU myself for ARM.  I've looked up the error message, but I can't seem to find anything relevant to my issue.

**FWIW:**

- The host is Ubuntu x64 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGA is a (more or less) x86-specific standard. As such, it is not available on ARM. A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811203/how-can-i-output-to-vga-through-qemu-arm): You can obtain graphics support using the ARM Versatile baseboard.

Seeing how your guide already sets the `-M versatilepb` option, you should be good to go as is. The kernel you're using already has support for the graphics solution on the emulated board.